# How to make a copy of a Parse Object in the Cloud?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to have a copy if an existing Parse Object, and then make some edits and save it as a new Parse Object rather than setting each field manually.

Here is my cloud function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SharePost", function(request, response) {
    var ShareUserID=request.params.ShareUserID;
    var UserID=request.params.UserID;
    var PostID=request.params.PostID;
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = new Parse.User({id:UserID});
    var shareuser = new Parse.User({id:ShareUserID});
    var query = new Parse.Query("Feed");
    query.get(PostID, {
    success: function(post) {
      var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Feed");
      var newpost = new Post()
      // here I would like to get the same object and make some edits o, it
      post.save( {
            success:function () {
                 response.success("Success");
            },
            error:function (pointAward, error) {
                 response.success(error);
            }
        }
    );    
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a prettier way, but one way that's sure to work without relying on any subtleties would be this:

```
function pfClone(fromObject, toObject, keys) {
    var _ = require('underscore');
    _.each(keys, function(key) {
        toObject.set(key, fromObject.get(key));
    });
}
```

call it like this:

```
// after fetching a post called "post"
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Feed");
var newpost = new Post();
var keys = ["title", "author" /* ...the keys you want to copy unchanged */ ];
pfClone(post, newpost, keys);
// change other properties of newpost here
```

Even prettier would be a version that introspects on the passed object, and then builds and initializes the clone.  The one inelegance for either of these ideas is that (last time I checked) PFObject doesn't let you introspect the keys, so you're stuck passing in an array of keys.